# Upgrading to spring 3.2.2 from 3.0.4, RequestBody String is getting escaped

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

we recently upgraded to spring 3.2.2 from 3.0.4. After upgrading we noticed that "RequestBody" parameter in our controller function is escaped or urlencoded. We updated schemaLocation to 3.2.xsd for spring-beans and spring-mvc.

For example in controller function below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFunnyFilters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getFunnyFilters(@RequestBody String body, HttpSession session) {
```

Value of body in 3.0.4 is

```
{"selectedFilters":{"values":[]}}
```

Whereas in 3.2.2 is

```
%7B%22selectedFilters%22%3A%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D=
```

Are we missing any settings or it is default behavior in 3.2.2. Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check what the content type is? You can find it in the headers of the HTTP request.

Comment: content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Can you try with `application/json`? That should fix it.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I thought spring will be backward compatible and also this code was working fine with 3.0.4 for last one year , therefore I am reluctant in making changes in header or in source code.

Comment: Maybe it was a bug that has been fixed. My current gut feeling is that the second output is correct when you use `x-www-form-urlencoded` because at least `{` is an illegal character that must be escaped. So the question is why Spring suddenly stopped to automatically decode the wire format.

Comment: If you stringify any complex JSON object it'll contain '{' or '}'. But what you are saying could be possible.